# Use surf in loop with data from struct

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot some data on a **surf** plot. 
The data is stored in a struct. Right now I'm able to use a loop to plot it on a 2D plot, but what I ultimately want is to use the **surf** function to assign the lines a color gradient as a function of a 3rd variable in this same loop.

This is the code I'm using right now for the 2D plots of **x** and **y** coordinates. In this case, every line has a different length (e.g. trajectory x1y1 is longer than x2y2).

The **results** struct can be found here: [DATA](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnNQmkzObMfSgSNVVagIt6hkHQ5Q?e=qEeUZ6)

```
for i1 = 1:2

    f = figure();
    if i1 == 1
        figName = 'Plot 1';
    elseif i1 == 2
        figName = 'Plot 2';
    end;
    set(f, 'Name', figName);

    hold all;
    for i2 = 1:nr_trajectories
        if ~isempty(results.x_before{i2, i1})
            plot([results.x_before{i2, i1}; results.x_ROI{i2, i1}; results.x_after{i2,i1}],...
                [results.y_before{i2, i1}; results.y_ROI{i2, i1}; results.y_after{i2, i1}]);

        end;
    end;

end;
```

I've used **surf** in the following context (for other stuff) to get some line plots (**x,y**) with a color gradient mapped linearly to variable **v**:

```
    x = rand(1000,1);
    y = rand(1000,1);
    v = rand(1000,1);

    figure;
    surf([x(:) x(:)], [y(:) y(:)], [v(:) v(:)], ...  
    'FaceColor', 'none', ...    
    'EdgeColor', 'interp', ...  
    'LineWidth', 3);            
    view(2);
```

My goal is to use this surf code inside the second **for loop** of the first piece of code.

Any ideia how I could go about this? Any input is very welcome :)

Cheers

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? It highly depends on how your data looks like, which we can not infer from the code posted

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you. Just added a file with the data from the 1st piece of code and added some lines to the second to generate mock data to plot. Cheer